# Sqlite get the average of combined two tables columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, full-outer-join

I have the following problem which i'm not sure how to approach a solution. I have the following db schema:

[image]
I want to get the median of both columns of both tables, filtered by userid, year and month. Doing this with two separate queries, i would do the following:

```
select avg(heartRate), avg (bodyWater) from table1 where user1d = 1234 and month = 1 and year = 2018

select avg(stepCount), avg (distance), avg (calories), avg (sleep) from table2 where user1d = 1234 and month = 1 and year = 2018
```

[image]

Then i would merge the result in code.

I want to accomplish the same with a single query, but there is a catch. If one table return no rows, i want to return default values of 0, in this particular case. I cannot use `ifnull` clause, because it only works if there is any row returned, not if no rows are found for one table. So my question is:
Is this a valid approach i should use, or this can't be done and i should stick to two queries and join the value in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the following tables (extended to cater for no row handling) :-

[image]

[image]

The query :-

```
SELECT avghr, avgbw, avgsc, avgdist, avgc, avgslp FROM 
    (SELECT avg(heartrate) AS avghr, avg(bodywater) AS avgbw
        FROM tbl1 where userid = 1234 AND year = 2018 AND month = 1),
    (SELECT avg(stepcount) AS avgsc, avg(distance) AS avgdist, avg(calories) AS avgc, avg(sleep) AS avgslp 
        FROM tbl2 where userid = 1234 AND year = 2018 AND month = 1)
```

results in :-

[image]

For month 2 :-

```
SELECT avghr, avgbw, avgsc, avgdist, avgc, avgslp FROM 
    (SELECT avg(heartrate) AS avghr, avg(bodywater) AS avgbw
        FROM tbl1 where userid = 1234 AND year = 2018 AND month = 2),
    (SELECT avg(stepcount) AS avgsc, avg(distance) AS avgdist, avg(calories) AS avgc, avg(sleep) AS avgslp 
        FROM tbl2 where userid = 1234 AND year = 2018 AND month = 2)
```

results in :-

[image]

For month 3 :-

```
SELECT avghr, avgbw, avgsc, avgdist, avgc, avgslp FROM 
    (SELECT avg(heartrate) AS avghr, avg(bodywater) AS avgbw
        FROM tbl1 where userid = 1234 AND year = 2018 AND month = 3),
    (SELECT avg(stepcount) AS avgsc, avg(distance) AS avgdist, avg(calories) AS avgc, avg(sleep) AS avgslp 
        FROM tbl2 where userid = 1234 AND year = 2018 AND month = 3)
```

results in :-

[image]

If you wanted 0's instead of nulls then the following, longwinded, SQL could be used :-

```
SELECT avghr, avgbw, avgsc, avgdist, avgc, avgslp, userid, year, month FROM 
    (SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN avg(heartrate) IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE avg(heartrate)
        END AS avghr,
        CASE
            WHEN avg(bodywater) IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE avg(bodywater)
        END AS avgbw
        FROM tbl1 where userid = 1234 AND year = 2018 AND month = 2),
    (SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN avg(stepcount) IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE avg(stepcount)
        END AS avgsc,
        CASE
            WHEN avg(distance) IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE avg(distance)
        END AS avgdist,
        CASE
            WHEN avg(calories) IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE avg(calories)
        END AS avgc,
        CASE 
            WHEN avg(sleep) IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE avg(sleep)
        END AS avgslp,
        userid, year, month 
            --???? not really needed 
            -- (if not used remove cols userid, year, month from primary/outer select)
            -- as well as from here.
        FROM tbl2 where userid = 1234 AND year = 2018 AND month = 2)
```

This would result in (for month 2, note SQL was saved to a view hence VIEW) :-

[image]

#### Notes

- Table names have been changed for convenience instead of **table1**, **tbl1** was used and likewise instead of **table2**, **tbl2** was used.
- column name **userid** was used instead of **user1d**
- The resultant cursor would have column names as per the result (avghr, avgbw etc.)
- The screen shots are from SQLite Manager, data is colour coded according to column type, as per Red = NULL, Green = INTEGER, DARKER GREEN=REAL, Blue = TEXT